Striations in steel corrision
Just curiosity but I ran some railroad spikes I had through electrolysis rust removal and one had striations:

Some of the needle like bits are quite sharp and be lifted up with some effort. What caused the spike to corrode like this?

@jsotola Fixed.

The striated structure is left over from the manufacturing process, which creates elongated grains along the length of the spike.
It is possible through very careful control of the electropolishing voltage to execute what is called a grain boundary etch which reveals the striations. It could be that you accidentally found the right voltage to bring out the striations.

Do you think it's that, or that Scorpio has gotten their hands on an actual wrought iron railroad spike?

WOW! never thought of that...
